Logstash - How to specify alternate settings directory in Docker Compose
Within Docker Compose yaml environment, we are able to override:

PATH_LOGS
LOG_FORMAT

But PATH_SETTINGS seems to be ignored.
Background: We are trying create one Docker image, but point to different pipelines.yml in 2 different environments.
Using Logstash 7.16.3
The logstash startup log shows lines like:

Setting path.logs from environment.
Setting log.format from environment.

But nothing for path.settings and it is uses the pipelines.yml in the default settings location.
We also tried alternate environment entries in Docker Compose yaml:

PATH.SETTINGS
SETTINGS


According to the logstash.yaml documentation, any config file entry can be set with an environment variable by transforming the setting name to uppercase and replacing special characters (.) with underscores.
There is no path.setting entry, so PATH_SETTING isn't going to configure anything. There is, however a path.config entry, so perhaps its PATH_CONFIG you are looking to set?
